# Suppose $x$ and $y$ are elements in a group $G$ with the order of $y$ not equal to $1$, $yx=xy^2$, and order of $x$ is $3$. Find the order of $y$.

Tags: group-theory

I have tried to figure out how to get rid of the $x$s on either side but because they're on opposite sides I can't figure out how to cancel them. I got $y=xyx^{-1}$  but I can't seem to find the order.

Does anyone have any ideas or hints?

Comment: Surely you mean $y = xy^2x^{-1}$. Now substitute $y^2$ in RHS for $y$ in this equation. (It may sound weird, but try it out!)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $y=xy^2x^2$ just by multiplying both sides by $x^2$ on the right. Call this equation $(\ast)$.

Now substitute $(\ast)$ into itself to get

$$y = x(xy^2x^2)^2x^2 = x^2y^4x \quad (\ast\ast).$$

Now substitute $(\ast)$ into $(\ast\ast)$. What do you get?

Comment: I see what you're getting at! thanks!